# Google Custom Search Style Issues

Tags: css, search, google-custom-search

I think I have a CSS issue with my Google Custom Search.

The search box and resutls that come up are not displaying correctly on my Custom Search.
The search box is squished and the "X" that shows up when the search is executed is not showing in the currect location.

Also, when the search is executed, the URL links are being "compressed".  The blue underline is not showing up and the bottom portion of the font is getting cut off.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

http://structurology.com/search

Comment: Is this only me or someone else who can't see a search box on the provided link page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gs-result`, `.gs-title` line height is too small it's `1.2em` make it `1.8em` that will fix the links and the underline.

as to the search box it's being affected by your `th`, `td`, `caption` padding.

Change .gscb_a font rule to the following for the X:

```
font: 27px/18px arial,sans-serif;
```